# Play audio via HTML audio tag

Tags: html, file, mp3, html5-audio

I have HTML document that is supposed to play the audio file via  tag.
My main problem is what kinda URL am I supposed to feed this tag in order for it to play.
For example, I have the file in folder completely different from HTML file, even stored on external SSD, and I have path to it, how do I play this file?

My code looks something like this:

```
<audio controls source="PathToFile"></audio>
```

Comment: that file should be in the same html, when you publish the web app. So you should mov that file to the same folder.

Comment: Is there ANY option for file not te be in same folder. I am building some kind of online DB, so I need to have external SSD with files on it....

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible to open arbitrary files from a user's local machine, as this has bad implications for security.

If you want to load local files, the user has to either select the directory/files with a `<input type="file">` element, or they have to drag/drop the directory/files so that you can get a reference that way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should have something likes this:

```
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="/sounds/The Wolven Storm (Priscilla's 
               song).mp3" 
  type="audio/mpeg"/>
</audio>
```

Answer (score -2):

If your website is hosted at some place that you have access to, your website is hosted on a local machine, and your SSD is plugged in to the same machine as your website, you could use absolute file paths inside of the quotes to achieve this.

for example:

`<audio controls src="C:/Absolute/File/Path/To/Audio.mp3"></audio>`

I hope this helped in answering your question.

Comment: I am using the absolute file path, but it seems that it can't be found. Is this absolute file path: /home/danilocongradac/Documents/AllSongs/Abba_-_Dancing_Queen (I am using ubuntu)

Comment: that is the absolute file path, but make sure to add the extension [(.mp3, .wav, etc.)(even if you can't see it in file explorer)]. If you did add the extension, it would be weird that it wasn't found.

Comment: I tried it on my machine and it works with an external SSD connected to the same computer (2015 MacBook Pro, shouldn't matter, though). Here is my code: [From Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/fbgReTSh). EDIT: changing `source=` to `src=` works. `source=` did not work when I tried it. Maybe that's the real error after all?

Comment: I tried what you just said, and still doesn't work. Maybe thing is that I am using spring MVC. However, I still get the same error. `Failed to load resource:  localhost:8080/home/danilocongradac/Documents/AllSongs/ABBA_-_Does_Your_Mother_Know.mp3 the server responded with a status of 404 ()`

Comment: why do you need the localhost:8080? can't your just do `/home/danilocongradac/Documents/AllSongs/ABBA_-_Does_Your_Mother_Know.mp3`

Comment: I dont think i can do it without localhost

Comment: have you tried? Try removing the port from `localhost` so it doesn't have to point to a particular place (IK it sounded a little confusing).

Comment: I am not sure how to do it without localhost, I am thinking to post this on local network with domain, so  I cant do it without. My line looks like this:    <audio controls src="${song.songPath}.mp3"></audio> I am using spring MVC, so that is how i get songPath

Comment: Can you please post more code so I can see how your program works? I am confused on why you need the song path variable.

Comment: So basicaly i am using Spring MVC, I have class Song that has songPath(path to that song), songName, and songArtist. I read all files from allSongs folder, and write them to arrayList of Songs, and display this arraylist on my webPage, where next to each song(represented as song name and song artist in one row) is this audio player. So src of this audio player is each songs path.

Comment: If all you're using Spring MVC for is those arrays and variables, would it be hard to ditch MVC and just hard code the file paths? Why you would prefer an array over that method, I'm still not sure.

Comment: I want to be able to add new mp3 files to this too, so i cant ditch MVC

Comment: Could you potentially use PHP or JavaScript to achieve the same task as MVC? I am guessing your intention with the program is: _Someone clicks to pick a song and the application picks the song based on the value in the array that the song was set with. Then, it scrapes all the metadata._ Correct?

Comment: I don't know anything about MVC which is why I'm asking.